# How to resolve "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set" error?

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as follow:

```
Sub intersection_1()
Dim rg1 As Range
Dim rg2 As Range
Set rg1 = Range("A:A")
Set rg2 = Range("5:5")
Intersect(Worksheets("Machine output").Range("21:21").Find(Sheets("History_1").Range("$D$4")), rg2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You should first test if the `Find` succeeded by assigning it to a `Range` variable, and then test `If Not theRangeVariable Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: You should also qualify the `Worksheet` for all `Range` calls.

Comment: Most importantly: there can be no cell that `Intersect`s both row 5 and row 21.

Answer (score 0):

As you are feeling your way into VBA it's best to go about it very methodical, meaning, don't try to mix `Find` and `Select` into a single command. Find first and select only after you found. Apply the same principle to `Find` input and `Find` output. Determine what you want to look for in a line of code that is separate from the line where you start your search.

And, of course, create the transparency you need also for the `Find` function itself. It has many arguments. You find them explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) and it will help you write clear code if you list them out methodically in a way you can check each one easily. If you observe these recommendations your code might look as follows.

```
Sub FindAndSelect()

    Dim SearchItem  As Variant              ' criterium to look for
    Dim DataRng     As Range                ' the range to search in
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' the cell found
    
    SearchItem = Worksheets("History_1").Cells(4, "D").Value
    Set DataRng = Worksheets("Machine Output").Rows(21)
    Set Fnd = DataRng.Find(What:=SearchItem, _
                           After:=DataRng.Cells(1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                           Searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Searchitem was found at " & Fnd.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "SearchItem was not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

All of the above is equivalent to only your last line of code but still omitting the `Select`. If the search is successful the output will be the address of a cell in 'Machine Output'!21:21 where the *SearchItem* was found. If you want to select that cell the command would be `Fnd.Select`.

Your code doesn't hint at the relationship of that result to either rg1 or rg2. But if you continue progressing methodically, one small step per new line of code, I'm sure you will be able to establish a connection that serves your purpose.